# git filtered log over submodules and as diffs

Tags: git, logging, diff, git-submodules

I'd need the output of

1. all commits in diff form
2. of a specific author
3. including submodules
4. ordered by date, not by submodule and then date

Is this possible at all?

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

```
git log --author=<name_andor_email> --date-order -p --submodule=diff
```

See https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log---submoduleltformatgt